# Getting stuck with Ubuntu logo

Tags: boot, 17.10

I have upgraded to 17.10 from 17.04 using software updater. I am using Dell Vostro laptop and Intel graphics driver is HD graphics card 520 Skylace GT2...

And also I can't access grub menu I have tried many times by pressing shift (right and left) keys but I can't the grub menu... but it shows me BIOS setup and some other option like change boot options.

Comment: Do you mean you turned it on by keeping Shift pressed? This might not work. Please try turning the computer on without any key pressed, then keep ticking it with your finger frantically, multiple times per second. This should show the GRUB menu.

Comment: Does pressing `Esc` during boot (the Ubuntu logo is shown) show the boot messages? What are the last ones when it gets stuck?